# How to perform process interrupts in jBPM based on business data

Tags: events, jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I've been doing some research into BPM solutions and am looking to hopefully use jBPM to achieve my goal. I am aware it is possible to start a process instance with an event signal sent to the process engine, but I would like to be able to interact with process instances currently running in that engine WITHOUT knowing their instance ID.

I am aiming to achieve this in an interrupt fashion by sending an event to the process engine, with business data, that will match to the process instance containing that specific match in business data (for instance a customer number unique to a process instance).

I have not yet been able to figure out how to do this, another of my goals is to expose this via REST/SOAP, and I am aware that this functionality is NOT currently implemented in the jBPM5 console REST interface.

How would I go about doing this, what are the standard patterns for doing so, or what other process engines should I be looking at to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can achieve that with jbpm and I would recommend you to check jbpm6 CR2.. 
In order to do what you need you can start multiple processes inside a KieSession and then send your customer as the payload of your event. Only the process that has that customer will catch the event ( if it's modeled correctly with the catch event node that filter by customer).

The Rest endpoints are already there in jbpm6.

Hope it helps